# Interface :- Alternative Approach

Tags: c#

I am beginner.Practicing in C# 3.0. The requirement is  "i have to design model in such a way that ,it should iterate through all classes which implement particular interface
(in this case `IExpressWords`) and execute the implemented method (`void ExpressWords()`)"

I collected all classes in a List and iterated.

```
namespace InterfaceExample
{
    public interface IExpressWords
    {
        void ExpressWords();
    }

    class GroupOne:IExpressWords
    {
        string[] str = { "Good", "Better", "Best" };
        public void ExpressWords()
        {
            foreach (string s in str)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }

    class GroupTwo:IExpressWords
    {
        string[] str = { "one", "two", "three" };
        public void ExpressWords()
        {
            foreach (string s in str)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<IExpressWords> word = new List<IExpressWords>();
            word.Add(new GroupOne());
            word.Add(new GroupTwo());
            foreach (IExpressWords Exp in word)
            {
                Exp.ExpressWords();
            }
           Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

}
```

**Questions :**

1. What is the name of this pattern ? (
   chain-of-responsibility? )
2. How can i achieve it using delegates
   ( I am not strong in delegates).
3. How can i find out all classes that
   implement the interface and execute
   the method using reflection
   ?(Curious to know ,how to tackle it
   using reflection).

(If i am not so clear in description,kindly let me know).

**Thanks all for the pouring perennial responses.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

2) Since the IExpressWords interface only contains a single method, it is effectively a wrapper around a method, which is what delegates are for. The equivalent delegate type is [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx). So your code would then become:

```
var groupOne = () => 
{
    foreach(string s in new[] { "Good", "Better", "Best" })
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

var groupTwo = () => 
{
    foreach(string s in new[] { "one", "two", "three" })
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

List<Action> acts = new List<action> { groupOne, groupTwo };
foreach(var a in acts)
{
    a();
}
```

3) To find all the types that implement an interface in the current assembly you can do this:

```
a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var implementingTypes = a.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IExpressWords).IsAssignableTo(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Action class to achieve this using delegates if you like

```
class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Action> word = new List<Action>();
            word.Add(new GroupOne().ExpressWords());
            word.Add(new GroupTwo().ExpressWords());

            foreach (Action del in word)
            {
                  del();
            }
           Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

if you want to use Delegates then you have to declare a Delegate type

```
delegate void SomeMethod();


class Test
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                List<SomeMethod> word = new List<SomeMethod>();
                word.Add(new GroupOne().ExpressWords());
                word.Add(new GroupTwo().ExpressWords());

                foreach (SomeMethod del in word)
                {
                      del();
                }
               Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the reflection case here is a small example :

```
static void WreakHavoc<T>(Action<T> havok)
{
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    var implementing = from assembly in assemblies
                       from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                       let interfaceType = typeof(T)
                       where interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(type)
                       select type;

    foreach(var type in implementing)
    {
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (ctor == null) continue;
        var instance = (T)ctor.Invoke(new object[0]);
        havok(instance);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    WreakHavoc<System.Collections.IEnumerable>((e) =>
    {
        foreach (var o in e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
    });
}
```